# DateTime format issue on StoredProcedure - C# ASP.NET x MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, sql-server-2014

I'm facing an issue while running an SQL Server 2014 stored procedure from my C# ASP.NET application (MVC 3).
When I manually run this procedure with the same parameters, it returns me all proper results. When the procedure is executed from the C# application, the "reader" comes empty, without any data. It seems to be an issue on the DateTime format. What should I do to solve it?
Here is the code:

SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc]
(
    @client_code AS varchar(7),
    @begin_date AS datetime,
    @end_date AS datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 


SELECT *
    from [dbo].[my_table] c
    WHERE c.code = @client_code
    AND c.date1 >= @begin_date
    AND c.date2 <= @end_date

END
```

C#:

```
DateTime Today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime LastYear = Today.AddYears(-1);
sql = new SqlConnection(/*my string connection*/);
sql.Open();
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "dbo.my_proc";
adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = sql;
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

param1 = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@client_code", SqlDbType.VarChar);
param1.Value = cod_client;

param2 = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@begin_date", SqlDbType.Date);
param2.Value = LastYear.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

param3 = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@end_date", SqlDbType.Date);
param3.Value = Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

reader = adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: `.ToString("...")`? No, you will have problems. Use `SqlDbType.DateTime` and use `Today.Date` if you want to drop the time part

Comment: You expect parameters of type DateTime, why do you convert your perfectly fit datetime variables to strings?

Comment: I was afraid of a datetime format mismatch between C# and SQL Server, so I tried to manage the format through toString method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't convert `DateTime` to string. just pass it "as-is" to the stored procedure. If you want just date part then use `Date`. Remember do not change the data type.

```
param2 = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@begin_date", SqlDbType.Date);
param2.Value = LastYear.Date;

param3 = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@end_date", SqlDbType.Date);
param3.Value = Today.Date;
```

Comment: I tried this way and it's not working as expected yet. I'm afraid of a datetime format mismatch.

Comment: I'm using this way for long time. would you please explain what went wrong?

Comment: The procedure is returning empty when executed from the C# application. However, when I manually run the procedure directly from SQL Server with the same parameters, all the proper rows are returned.

Comment: i don't think the DateTime is the problem. please insert the input DateTime in a table in order to trace the problem.

Comment: Can you use casting and try once? like cast(c.date1 as date) >= cast(@begin_date as date)

Answer (score 0):

Try the AddWithValue method wich is less verbose and can identify the DataType of the parameter on the fly:

```
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_code", cod_client);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begin_date", LastYear.Date);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end_date", Today.Date);
```

Comment: This doesn't tackles on the root problem (sending date values as text) and most important [AddWithValue is a bad practice anyway](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).